# no memory in hardisk when try to print log using printstream

Tags: java

Our sip proxy server got hanged .At the time no log were printed . then we found that no memory in the hardisk. i wounder that if no memory to print log  why should server get hanged?. because i have set heap memory and stack memory(i hope that is reserverd memory) to run java sip proxy server .any one suggest me , following code we are using to print

```
PrintStream ps=System.out;
public void log(){
try {
ps.println(msg);
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean; how do I handle running our of disk space?

I would only catch an Exception when you can do something useful with it.

I also suggest you use a logging library such as the one built into the JDK or one of the many open source libraries like `slf4j`

Comment: if i try to print log about processing information , what if no spaces in hardisk, what kind of cause would happen?? how would java(jvm) response??